# Generate Blurhash code in Next JS app for a dynamic images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file-upload, next.js

i'm using next JS and dropzone to upload an image and send the images to a server. i learned that next JS uses blur hash for static images when used as 'blur' in placeholder. but when it comes to dynamic images fetched from server it needs to be passed the blurhash as well.

so is there a way that i could generate BlurHash myself when i upload images and send them to server? i don't want to use API to generate these hash codes. just pure javascript

dropzone accepted images

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const images = useSelector(selectImages);
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(images == [] ? [] : images);

const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
     acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = async function (e) {
          const options = {
            maxSizeMB: 5,
            maxWidthOrHeight: 1920,
            useWebWorker: true,
          };
          const compressedFile = await imageCompression(file, options);

          const tot = parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) + parseInt(files.length);
          if (tot > 9) {
            alert("select maximum of 9 images");
          } else if (parseInt(acceptedFiles.length) > 9) {
            alert("maximum images to be selected is 9");
          } else if (parseInt(files.length) < 9) {
            setFiles((prevState) => [
              ...prevState,
              {
                id: index,
                src: URL.createObjectURL(compressedFile),
                name: file.name,
              },
            ]);

            files.map((filename) => {
              acceptedFiles.forEach((newFile) => {
                if (newFile.name == filename.name) {
                  alert("a duplicate image is detected");

                  setFiles(
                    files,
                    files.filter((val) => val !== newFile)
                  );
                }
              });
            });
          } else {
            alert("something went wrong");
          }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return file;
      });
    },
})
```

and the output when uploaded

[image: output]